# How to use EntityFramework.BulkInsert?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, extension-methods, bulkinsert

I'm trying to use EntityFramework.BulkInsert located at http://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/. It's an extension for Entity Framework.

I installed the proper NuGet package and added `using EntityFramework.BulkInsert` to the top of my class. When I go to do a `context.BulkInsert(entities)` "BulkInsert" has a red line underneath as if it doesn't exist. Can someone help me in the proper usage of this extension? I haven't used an extension method before. You are supposed to be able to just do this:

```
context.BulkInsert(entities);
```

Comment: what is `entities`?  Looking at the docs, looks like the parameter is to take in an IEnumerable

Comment: yeah it's just a parameter to take in a collection of entities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add

```
using EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions;
```

to the top of your class