# Insert large amount of data into database using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I want to insert around 1 million records into a database using Linq in ASP.NET MVC. But when I try the following code it didn't work. It's throwing an `OutOfMemoryException`. And also it took 3 days in the loop. Can anyone please help me on this???

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE From [HotelServices]");

DataTable tblRepeatService = new DataTable();
tblRepeatService.Columns.Add("HotelCode",typeof(System.String));
tblRepeatService.Columns.Add("Service",typeof(System.String));
tblRepeatService.Columns.Add("Category",typeof(System.String));

foreach (DataRow row in xmltable.Rows)
{
     string[] servicesarr = Regex.Split(row["PAmenities"].ToString(), ";");

     for (int a = 0; a < servicesarr.Length; a++)
     {
         tblRepeatService.Rows.Add(row["HotelCode"].ToString(), servicesarr[a], "PA");
     }

     String[] servicesarrA = Regex.Split(row["RAmenities"].ToString(), ";");

     for (int b = 0; b < servicesarrA.Length; b++)
     {
         tblRepeatService.Rows.Add(row["hotelcode"].ToString(), servicesarrA[b], "RA");
     }
}

HotelAmenties _hotelamenties;

foreach (DataRow hadr in tblRepeatService.Rows)
{
     _hotelamenties = new HotelAmenties();
     _hotelamenties.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     _hotelamenties.ServiceName = hadr["Service"].ToString();
     _hotelamenties.HotelCode = hadr["HotelCode"].ToString();

     db.HotelAmenties.Add(_hotelamenties);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

`tblRepeatService` table has around 1 million rows.

Comment: Use `SqlBulkCopy` for bulk operations - Linq-to-EF isn't optimized and designed for bulk operations. [See the relevant MSDN docs for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You can use [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332863/entityframework-bulkinsert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk inserts like this are highly inefficient in LINQtoSQL.  Every insert creates at least three objects (the `DataRow`, the `HotelAmenities` object and the tracking record for it), chewing up memory on objects you don't need.

Given that you already have a `DataTable`, you can use [`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to push the content of the table to a temporary table on the SQL server, then use a single `insert` statement to load the data into its final destination.  This is the fastest way I have found so far to move many thousands of records from memory to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If performance doesn't matter and this is a 1 shot job you can stick to the way you're using. Your problem is you're only saving at the end, so entity Framework has to store and generate the SQL for 1 million operations at once, modify your code so that you save every 1000 or so inserts instead of only at the end and it should work just fine.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow hadr in tblRepeatService.Rows)
{ 
     _hotelamenties = new HotelAmenties();
     _hotelamenties.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     _hotelamenties.ServiceName = hadr["Service"].ToString();
     _hotelamenties.HotelCode = hadr["HotelCode"].ToString();

     db.HotelAmenties.Add(_hotelamenties);
     if((i%1000)==0){
     db.SaveChanges();
     }
     i++;
}    
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Don't forget to drop the context and create a new one! The old one keeps references anyhow...

Comment: That may not be an issue, my gut feeling is it's throwing an OOM exception while building the sql query, not due to the object graph, but yes if what i posted doesn't work it would be a good idea to partition them by 1K beforehand and then move the using context within the foreach group loop. If this doesn't solve the user issue i'll update my answer with this